# Calling Sinatra's DSL methods from Sinatra extensions

Tags: ruby, web-applications, module, sinatra, modular

I have a modular Sinatra app and am looking for the most straightforward way to call Sinatra API-level methods (such as `get()`) from inside other modules. I figured Sinatra extensions would be it, but something's not working.

This is the main file that imports all other modules:

**app/app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'articles', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }

module Tir
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::Blog

    get '/articles' do
      articles = parse_articles('articles/*.mdown')
    end

  end 
end
```

This is the method from inside which I'm calling `get()` — and cannot:

**app/articles/blog.rb**

```
module Sinatra
  module Blog

  ARTICLES = []

  def parse_articles(dir)
    Dir.glob(dir) do |file|
      article = initialize_article file
      if article.ready?
        generate_path(article)
        ARTICLES << article
      end
    end
  end

  def generate_path(article)
    get("/#{article.relative_path}") do
      erb :'articles/article',
      :locals => { :article => article },
      :layout => :'articles/layout_article'
    end
  end

  end
  register Blog
end
```

**config.ru**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require_relative 'app/app'

run Tir::App
```

When I run this, I get `undefined method 'parse_articles' for #<Tir::App:0x00007f9b6536c5d8>`.

What's not right here? Thanks.

Comment: This seems correct to me, what’s happening when you run this?

Comment: I am sorry, my question was a bit misleading. It's not the get() method that isn't working but the extension methods in general. I've modified the source code listing accordingly. When I run the above, I get "undefined method `parse_articles' for #<Tir::App:0x00007f9b6536c5d8>"